# How to return a python data structure to C#

Tags: c#, python-3.x

Python3.6

How do I return a specified data structure from a C# library to a python program?

I have the core of some programs written in C# and would like to access this code using Python to scale up the operational ability of the code. At this point I'm just trying to confirm that I can access the C# code from within a python program in order to validate the process.

I have this function in C#, to call from python.

file;

IOLibrary.cs

```
[DllExport("readData", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static List<TrainRecord> readData(string filename, List<string> trainList, bool excludeListOfTrains, DateTime[] dateRange)
```

and file;

TrainLibrary.cs contains the data structures

```
namespace TrainLibrary
{
  public class TrainRecord
  {
      public string trainID;
      public string locoID;
      public DateTime dateTime;
      public GeoLocation location;
      public trainOperator trainOperator;
      public trainCommodity commodity;
      public double kmPost;
      public double speed;
      public double powerToWeight;
...
```

The trainOperator and trainCommodity are enumerated types, and the rest is self explanatory.

The python code to access the function is:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import clr
clr.AddReference( r"<full path>\IOLibrary.dll")
clr.AddReference( r"<full path>\TrainLibrary.dll")

from IOLibrary import FileOperations
#from TrainLibrary import TrainRecord, trainCommodity, trainOperator, GeoLocation

file = 'file_to_read.txt'
excludeTrainList = ["item1","item2","item3"]
dateRange = [datetime(2018, 1, 1), datetime(2018, 2, 1)]

a = FileOperations()

fileOpInstance = FileOperations()
# records needs to be a List<Trainrecords> ?
records = fileOpInstance.readData(file, excludeTrainList, False, dateRange)
print (len(records))
```

This code runs fine for a simple example returning "Hello World", but when I run the code to access the function I need, I get the error:

```
No method matches given arguments for readData
```

Now, I'm sure this is related to how I'm passing in the dateRange or how I'm returning the results.

I tried including the commented out line

```
from TrainLibrary import TrainRecord, trainCommodity, trainOperator, GeoLocation
```

in the python program, but I get this error:

```
No module named 'TrainLibrary'
```

How to i make Python understand the C# data structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I had to include the DLLExport using directives in the TrainLibrary.cs file to access the data structures.

TrainLibrary.cs

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
```

Then importing the data structures by name

Python program

```
clr.AddReference( r"<full path>\TrainLibrary.dll")
from TrainLibrary import TrainRecord, trainCommodity, trainOperator, GeoLocation
...
```